# Oauth - What Kind of Permissions should be given in default login token?

Tags: php, python, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm working on an authentication system for a web application I am making. I want to allow other apps to connect to the data stored in mine (using an OAuth system).

I've been reading about how OAuth works here: https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/background/

Most of it makes sense, however I do have one problem:

How do I make it so the user does not have to grant access to my own mobile apps?

In other words, how can I make it so the server automatically grants certain permissions to my mobile apps?
I assume part of this involves creating a client ID and client secret for those apps, just like the others, but how could I securely bypass the grant from those applications?

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly, because in my API I have a `signIn` endpoint that takes a username and password and returns an auth token.

Should I just not have a `signIn` endpoint, and instead just have a token validator that hands off to the OAuth system if the token is invalid?

I know that's a lot of questions, but I want to get this right since the authentication system is so important to security.

Comment: `access` permissions should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question about the mobile clients, there is the [OAuth2 for Native Apps RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252) which discusses the topic. In short, you should use the authorization code grant with [PKCE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) and refresh tokens, so your mobile apps need to ask for authorization just once. To do it, your mobile apps will need to be registrated OAuth2 clients and the `token` endpoint should be configured not to require secret (since you cannot keep secrets in mobile apps).

For the second part, one of the benefits of the OAuth2 protocol is that only the auth server gets user credentials - not the applications. It makes the credentials harder to get compromised and allows users to delegate only certain rights (scopes). So it would be good to stick to some of the basic OAuth2 flows (auth code, implicit, hybrid) and not to use your own endpoint for authentication. It will make your application safer and maybe even easier to use (if you use things like [SSO](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would also like to ask how OAuth works without  a client secret. Since the client ID is considered public information, how do you make sure you are not impersonated?

Comment: I think if you use [Claimed "https" Scheme](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8252#section-7.2) for redirect URIs, operating systems should guarantee the identity of the app using a given client_id. So an attacker's app should not be able to use your client_id and get an auth code. But I don't know how it's implemented in operating systems.

Comment: Ok, and lastly, should I have a `signUp` endpoint, so my apps can create accounts from the device?